# Fiddler showing 404 but the site is loading

Tags: c#, api, http

Wen m trying to fire an api through the fiddler, its showing 404. On the other hand, the site is loading properly.[image: This is the fiddler ss m sharing. the same site is png properly in chrome]

Comment: Loading a site is a `GET` request not a `POST` one

Comment: But that is not the issue, as locally it is working fine with post only

Comment: This is unanswerable in its current form. Why are you stating a content-length but not sending a body? Whose API is it? What does a request look like that doesn't end up with a 404? What are you trying to do, actually?

Answer (score 0):

Your sites loads successfully, cause your 2nd request shows a 200 for localhost (and I bet this is a GET request). After the site is loaded, it seems to contain some javascript code that tries to connect to some login site (with POST to aaweb.authorassists.com) and that fails.